# Understanding this part of this Header file

Tags: c, gcc, macros, typedef, c-preprocessor

```
#ifndef STDARG_H_INCLUDED
#define STDARG_H_INCLUDED

typedef __builtin_va_list va_list;

#define va_start(v,l)   __builtin_va_start(v,l) // I don't understand this
#define va_arg(v,l)     __builtin_va_arg(v,l)
#define va_end(v)       __builtin_va_end(v)

#endif
```

It seems that the author defines some kind of a macro function, but I don't understand how this function works?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
#define va_start(v,l)   __builtin_va_start(v,l)
```

simply means `va_start(v,l)` will be replaced by `__builtin_va_start(v,l)`, and this `__builtin_va_start()` is obviously a builtin function or macro, it is implemented by the compiler or libc itself.